# Making tabs automatically rotate? ¿Hacer que las pestañas giren automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not very proficient in JS and would like to help me with an issue I have. I want to make the tabs on a Drupal website automatically rotate but still the user to be able to click on them. This is the code I have:

No soy muy competente en JS y me gustaría ayudarme con un problema que tengo. Quiero hacer que las pestañas de un sitio web de Drupal giren automáticamente, pero aún así el usuario puede hacer clic en ellas. Este es el código que tengo:

primero esta el jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script >
    var index = 0, // Index of current tab
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000), // Interval
    $tabs = $('ul.checklist-select'),
    $content = $('.checklist_wrap');

// Click handler
$('ul.checklist-select>li>a').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        index = i;
        switchElement();
    });
});

function rotate() {
    // Update index to next one
    index++;

    // Check if this is a valid index, or reset to 0
    if (index >= $tabs.children('li>a').length)
        index = 0;

    switchElement();
}

function switchElement() {
    // Clear interval
    clearInterval(interval);

    // Remove class from current tab
    $('ul.checklist-select>li>a').removeClass('active');
    $('.checklist_wrap>div>div.box').fadeOut(300);

    // Show
    var $tab = $tabs.children('li>a').eq(index);
    $tab.addClass('active');
    $content.children('div>div.box').eq(index).delay(300).fadeIn(300);

    // Reset interval
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000);
}
</script>

cómo esto
```

primero est es el html

```
<div id="checklist_wrap">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs checklist-select" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link active cartelera" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#cartelera" role="tab" aria-controls="cartelera" aria-selected="true"> cartelera</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link gallo" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#gallo" role="tab" aria-controls="gallo" aria-selected="false">gallo</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link calendario" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#calendario" role="tab" aria-controls="calendario" aria-selected="false">Calendario</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link galeria" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#galerias" role="tab" aria-controls="galerias" aria-selected="false">Galerias</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item video">
            <a class="nav-link video" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#videos" role="tab" aria-controls="videos" aria-selected="false">Videos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content p-3 tabs-cartelera" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active box" id="cartelera" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">uno</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="gallo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">dos</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="calendario" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">tres</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="galerias" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">cuatro</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="videos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried few options but it wasn't working.Thanks very much! I appreciate your time and help.

Probé algunas opciones pero no funcionaba. ¡Muchas gracias! Agradezco tu tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: Como es un sitio en español podrías editar la pregunta y dejarla sin lo de ingles.

Comment: lo intentado por los dos medios y no encontrado respuesta

Comment: @Alexanderaguilar, va a ser más difícil que te respondan si tu pregunta no es clara o no sigues las reglas del sitio.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Hacer que las pestañas giren automáticamente?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/360350/hacer-que-las-pesta%c3%b1as-giren-autom%c3%a1ticamente)

Comment: Por favor no dupliques preguntas, recuerda que quienes participan en estos sitios no están todo el día conectados y no vas a obtener respuestas como si estuvieras en un chat o en un sitio de soporte, debes tener paciencia.