# ¿Hacer que las pestañas giren automáticamente?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drupal

me gustaria que me ayudaran porfavor No soy muy competente en JS y me gustaría ayudarme con un problema que tengo. Quiero hacer que las pestañas de un sitio web de `Drupal` giren automáticamente, pero aún así el usuario puede hacer clic en ellas. Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora , alguien que me ayude por favor:
seque hay forma de realizar esta tarea deforma mas corta o una manera mas didactica.

```js
    var index = 0, // Index of current tab
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000), // Interval
    $tabs = $('ul.checklist-select'),
    $content = $('.checklist_wrap');

// Click handler
$('ul.checklist-select>li>a').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        index = i;
        switchElement();
    });
});

function rotate() {
    // Update index to next one
    index++;

    // Check if this is a valid index, or reset to 0
    if (index >= $tabs.children('li>a').length)
        index = 0;

    switchElement();
}

function switchElement() {
    // Clear interval
    clearInterval(interval);

    // Remove class from current tab
    $('ul.checklist-select>li>a').removeClass('active');
    $('.checklist_wrap>div>div.box').fadeOut(300);

    // Show
    var $tab = $tabs.children('li>a').eq(index);
    $tab.addClass('active');
    $content.children('div>div.box').eq(index).delay(300).fadeIn(300);

    // Reset interval
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="checklist_wrap">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs checklist-select" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link active cartelera" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#cartelera" role="tab" aria-controls="cartelera" aria-selected="true"> cartelera</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link gallo" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#gallo" role="tab" aria-controls="gallo" aria-selected="false">gallo</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link calendario" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#calendario" role="tab" aria-controls="calendario" aria-selected="false">Calendario</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link galeria" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#galerias" role="tab" aria-controls="galerias" aria-selected="false">Galerias</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item video">
            <a class="nav-link video" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#videos" role="tab" aria-controls="videos" aria-selected="false">Videos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content p-3 tabs-cartelera" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active box" id="cartelera" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">uno</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="gallo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">dos</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="calendario" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">tres</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="galerias" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">cuatro</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="videos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

probé algunas opciones pero no funcionaba. ¡Muchas gracias! Agradezco su tiempo y ayuda.

Comment: Las ediciones de las preguntas se hacen para que sean más legibles y textos como este _me gustaria que me ayudaran porfavor No soy muy competente en JS y me gustaría ayudarme con un problema que tengo._, saludos o agradecimientos no ayudan a plantear correctamente la pregunta, es mejor _ir directamente al grano_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funcionó con algunos pequeños cambios:

- Obtener contenedores por ID y no por etiqueta.clase
- En `rotate` solo cambié `$tabs.children('li>a')` por `$tabs.find('a.nav-link')` para obtener los enlaces disponibles
- En `switchElement` es donde hubo más cambios y están comentados.

Básicamente, no funcionaba por la forma de obtener los elementos o por como intentabas modificarlo, además de que no actualizabas las clases correctamente.

```js
var index = 0, // Index of current tab
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000), // Interval
    // Obtener ul y div por ID
    $tabs = $('#myTab'),
    $content = $('#myTabContent');

// Click handler
$('ul.checklist-select>li>a').each(function (i) {
    $(this).click(function () {
        index = i;
        switchElement();
    });
});

function rotate() {
    // Update index to next one
    index++;

    // Check if this is a valid index, or reset to 0
    // Verificar la cantidad de enlaces
    if (index >= $tabs.find('a.nav-link').length)
        index = 0;

    switchElement();
}

function switchElement() {
    // Clear interval
    clearInterval(interval);

    // Remove class from current tab
    $('ul.checklist-select>li>a').removeClass('active');
    // Eliminar clases que hacen visibles los div
    $content.children().removeClass('show active');
    $content.children().fadeOut(300);

    // Show
    // Buscar por enlace y seleccionar por índice
    var $tab = $tabs.find('a.nav-link')[index];
    $($tab).addClass('active');
    // Buscar por índice y agregar clase para hacerlo visible
    $($content.children()[index]).addClass('show active');
    $($content.children()[index]).fadeIn(300);

    // Reset interval
    interval = setInterval(function () { rotate(); }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="checklist_wrap">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs checklist-select" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link active cartelera" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#cartelera" role="tab" aria-controls="cartelera" aria-selected="true"> cartelera</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link gallo" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#gallo" role="tab" aria-controls="gallo" aria-selected="false">gallo</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link calendario" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#calendario" role="tab" aria-controls="calendario" aria-selected="false">Calendario</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link galeria" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#galerias" role="tab" aria-controls="galerias" aria-selected="false">Galerias</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item video">
            <a class="nav-link video" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#videos" role="tab" aria-controls="videos" aria-selected="false">Videos</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content p-3 tabs-cartelera" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active box" id="cartelera" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">uno</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="gallo" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">dos</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="calendario" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">tres</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="galerias" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">cuatro</div>

        <div class="tab-pane fade box" style="display: none;" id="videos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">cinco</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias pero me sale un error...

Comment: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined at rotate

Comment: y este $ is not defined
    at

Comment: en esta linea   $tabs = $('#myTab'),
    $content = $('#myTabContent');

Comment: Prueba actualizando tu versión de jQuery, es muy antigua (1.9.1)

Comment: $content.children(...).fadeOut is not a function

Comment: ya solucione lo anterior pero el drupal me manda este error

Comment: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: ¿Sigues obteniendo error? ¿Cuál es?